# Was Anna Faris bound to a strict diet before filming 'The House Bunny'?

Tags: the-house-bunny

Was Anna Faris bound to a strict diet before filming 'The House Bunny'?

She looked amazing in the movie.

Was weight loss written into her contract when she signed up for the movie?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anna Faris wasn't just the *leading actress*, she also [pitched the idea](http://www.indielondon.co.uk/Film-Review/the-house-bunny-anna-faris-interview) and [served as an executive producer](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0852713/fullcredits#producers), so she certainly knew early on what she was getting herself into.

About [getting in the right shape](http://www.instyle.com/instyle/package/general/photos/0,,20225467_20225469_20509128,00.html):

> **Faris worked with her trainer and pilates instructor**, Nicole Stuart, six days a week, ran a minimum of three miles per day **and maintained a very strict diet**.
>
> - *“You know how you read that all of these actresses eat nothing but chicken and steamed vegetables to stay so thin, well I had to do that. I would watch the other girls loading up on fries at craft services and be snacking away on a piece of celery.”*
>
> Since filming wrapped, Faris has eased up on her diet and exercise routine.
>
> - *"I could never maintain that. Nor would I want to!”*